# search for column name in laravel to get rows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i have two table(jobs,skills) 
skills[image]
jobs[image]

i want to search by laravel for jobs by skill. when i write html -> 
1-(search for column name) 
2-(get rows where that column equal 1 )
 3-(get jobs where job_id(table job) = job_id(table skill)

that my code

```
$search_name = $request->input('search');
$skillscolumns =  DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('skills');

//1
$query = Skill::select('*');
foreach($skillscolumns as $column) {
   $query->where($column, '=', $search_name);
}
$searchedColumn = $query->get();

//2
foreach ($searchedColumn  as  $value) {
    $skillRows = collect($value)->filter(function ($value){ return $value === 1;})->get();
}

//3
foreach ( $skillRows  as  $value) {
    $wantedJobs = Job::where('job_id',$value->job_id)->get();
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i want to search for column name in skills table

Comment: What part of your code isn't working?

Comment: //1
$query = Skill::select('*');
foreach($skillscolumns as $column) {
   $query->where($column, '=', $search_name);
}
$searchedColumn = $query->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$jobs = [];
if(in_array($request->search, (new Skill)->getFillable())){
    $ids = Skill::where($request->search, true)->get()->pluck('job_id');
    if($ids){
        $jobs = Job::find($ids);
    }
}
```